How can I block for one request at a time, and when it completes, then process the most recent, completing older requests with no processing?
I am displaying pins on a map. When the user scrolls or zooms out, I now have additional pins to display. If the move will add 50,000 more pins, that can take 4 - 10 seconds as the DB query is complex and therefore can take time.
This is all in a Blazor server web app and all the calls are Task events so the user moves, the get more pins starts, the UI remains responsive, the user moves some more, another event is sent, etc.
I presently use a SemaphoreSlim to insure only 1 move gets processed at a time. With a reasonable level of activity on the user's part, this can back up with 5 tasks waiting for their turn to get more pins.
However, if there are 4 tasks waiting, the most recent is the only one that matters. If it is handled, then the displayed map will show all desired pins. Any earlier task waiting is now irrelevant.
What I would like to do when a task completes and there are 2+ waiting is:

Process the newest task.
Complete all of the tasks before that task.
Repeat if additional task(s) have come in while doing this.

I do not want to cancel the task in process when additional tasks come in because showing something is better than the user keeps moving, the queries keep getting cancelled, nothing updates for them. So complete the one on, then handle the waiting group.
How can I do this?
(I've tried saving the requests off, their parameters and a DateTime stamp, and then processing. and on the mutex releasing, checking for each task going to run to see if it can just return success. But what I have is a complex mess that I'm guessing is buggy.)

Have you considered using Queue?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-8.0

@RobertJ. Unfortunately that isn't what I want as I want the last in (stack) and to delete all other entries. And to have the other Tasks remain pending and then return when the last in completes processing.

@DavidThielen - So [edit] your question and specify that fact.

@SecurityHound I believe I said that with "Complete all of the tasks before that task."

This question is discussed on Meta

Shouldn't a (thread safe or manually locked) stack data structure work? Because its nature is "last in/first out" which is what you want. Requests go on the stack. When it's time to work on the next request, you always pop the newest one from the stack and then empty the stack (thus discarding the obsolete requests) in an atomic (i.e. synchronized) single action.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica yes & yes. I came up with a simpler solution than that (see below) but your suggestion is a good approach too.

I found a simple approach. This works because when a search ends, I only want the most recent query to run. All other pending queries can be discarded (and their tasks completed).
I declare:
/// <summary>
/// The map does not like multiple queries at once. So we use a mutex to ensure only one
/// runs at a time. THe few times this hits, there's only 2 so no point in coalescing all
/// the calls.
/// </summary>
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

/// <summary>
/// This is an increasing counter used to discard out of date map search queries.
/// </summary>
private long _mapSearchCounter;

Then at the start of my method I have:
var myCounter = Interlocked.Increment(ref _mapSearchCounter);

await _mutex.WaitAsync();

// if there's another LATER task to search, then we can skip this one.
var latestCounter = Interlocked.Read(ref _mapSearchCounter);
if (myCounter < latestCounter)
    return true;

And at the end of the method, in a finally, I have:
_mutex.Release();

The blocked tasks can be released in any order, where the older ones all return immediately and the latest performs the query and updates the pins.

This should work well. To make it a bit less messy you could encapsulate the SemaphoreSlim and the _mapSearchCounter in a dedicated class, named for example AsyncMutex. The bool isLatest = await _mutex.WaitAsync(); would return a bool value that would be true if there is no newer WaitAsync operation pending.

One idea is to ditch the SemaphoreSlim, and use instead an asynchronous processing loop that takes items from a queue and processes them one at a time. As queue you could use a bounded Channel<T> with capacity 1, configured to discard the oldest item when there is no space for the newest item:
Channel<PinRequest> pinRequests = Channel.CreateBounded<PinRequest>(
    new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity: 1)
{
    FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest,
});

async Task ProcessPinsAsync()
{
    await foreach (PinRequest pinRequest in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        await ProcessPinRequestAsync(pinRequest);
    }
}

To add a new PinRequest in the queue:
pinRequests.Writer.TryWrite(new PinRequest());

Clarification: In the above example the PinRequest does not represent an active Task. It represents the state required to launch a Task. The Task is launched by the ProcessPinRequestAsync method. So a PinRequest is something that can be safely discarded. You won't have to worry about "completing" it.

Thank you - that's a clever way to get the newest. However, how do I complete the tasks of the discarded requests? TIA

@DavidThielen in general you can't complete a Task. You can only Wait/await it to complete, or cancel it if it's associated with a CancellationTokenSource to which your code has access. Are your tasks controllable by associated TaskCompletionSources by any chance?

No. They call this method which returns a Task. The present approach blocking on a mutex works because when they each get their turn, they run the query, populate the pins, and return the completed task. And I need that task to run the query. Only the most recent task, but I need that. This is definitely not a simple problem :) thanks
